Add multiple heights per feature in the attribute table in QField
I would like to measure a dam and enter the heights of different components directly into the attribute table. Is it possible to transfer, beside the height of the geometry, the other heights in the attribute form with one click when repositioning the measuring rod or do I have to enter them manually or create a separate feature for each height?
I want to click in the field (e.g. height_1) in QField to transfer the current height of the GPS device. Then I want to reposition the GPS device, click in the field height_2 and transfer the new current height of the GPS device to this field.

@Bera: This means that I want to click in the field (e.g. height_1) in Qfield to transfer the current height of the GPS device. Then I want to reposition the GPS device, click in the field height_2 and transfer the new current height of the GPS device to this field.
